# From list to n vectors in R

Tags: r, list, loops

I guess my question is two-fold

I have a list of n data frames.
I want to make n data frames b1, b2, b3... bn so I can more easily access the data for some other functions.

For example, when I use `hist(log(b[[1]]$var))` I get all sorts of errors,

but if instead, I first do `b1 = b[[1]]`, then `hist(log(b1))` gives me no problems.

1. How do I create the n data frames b1, b2... bn from my list of n objects AND/OR
2. If I can't make b1,b2...bn separate data frames, how would I pass the objects through functions reliably in the original `b[[1]]` form?

Answer (score 0):

**edited version**

I think I misunderstood your problem.

**b[[1]]$var** should *not* give you a problem if **b[[1]]** is really a data.frame.

So, my hunch is that the items of your list **b** are not data.frame (at least one of them should not be).

To convert an object to a data.frame, use as.data.frame. So to correct your problem, this fix should do the trick:

```
for (i in seq_along(b)) {
    b[[i]] <- as.data.frame(b[[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l <- list(df1=data.frame(a=1:5), df2=data.frame(a=6:10)) # example list
names(l) <- paste0("b", 1:length(l)) # rename df's in list to b_n
list2env(l, envir=globalenv()) # b1 and b2 are now directly addressable
```

Comment: Ah I had already renamed all the list objects to b1, b2 etc... so the list2env(l, envir=globalenv()) is kinda like attaching them? Thanks luke.

Comment: @user3330466 Have a look at `?list2env`. It puts all (named) list components as objects into the global environment, which contains the data frames, functions etc that you can access from everywhere.